# Profanity Filter: I just need some help on how to make it recognize _only_ the values in an array

Tags: java

```
    /*

    Profanity Filter:
    - Cat
    - Dog
    - LLama
    - Has to differ cases, like cAt
    - Has to differ words that contain the words to be filtered, "Cataclysm", for example. Hello, World of Warcraft.

*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProfanityFilter
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput, toLowerCase;
        boolean flag = false;
        int i;
        String[] list = new String[12];
        list[0] = "cat";
        list[1] = " cat";
        list[2] = "cat ";
        list[3] = " cat ";
        list[4] = "dog";
        list[5] = " dog";
        list[6] = "dog ";
        list[7] = " dog ";
        list[8] = "llama";
        list[9] = " llama";
        list[10] = "llama ";
        list[11] = " llama ";

        System.out.println("Enter a string:");
        userInput = kb.nextLine();
        toLowerCase = userInput.toLowerCase();

        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            if(toLowerCase.contains(list[i]) | toLowerCase.equals(list[i]))
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        if (flag)
        {
            System.out.println("Something you said is forbidden.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Nothing was found");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just having trouble finding the proper exception to what I need. I know I'm pretty close, but I'm also tired after trying many many hours to solve this problem and coming out empty of a solution that will return true for the instances I need (the ones in the array). Can you point me out to what I'm doing wrong in here or to a proper solution without regular expressions?

I've already tried to put a break; after I turn the boolean flag to true but it didn't work, it keeps iterating and thus the output keeps being false.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't say what you wanted to happen, but I'm guessing you just want to use the keyword `break;`.

Comment: I think you're looking for `break;`

Comment: Thing is, I've tried to use a break; after the flag becomes true, but it keeps iterating through the array thus turning the flag false when it checks other values.

Comment: Nothing in your code remotely suggests any way that could happen.  You never, even conditionally, set the flag to false.  The worst that could happen if you don't break is that you waste time checking the rest of the array and redundantly set flag to true multiple times.

Comment: Except for the initialization `boolean flag = false;`. This suggests that the condition is never met. OP, have you set a breakpoint in your debugger to see if the condition ever evaluates to `true`?

Comment: @azurefrog well, like I said, I used break; and it still kept checking out the other values, that's what I'm confused about, I thought a break; would exit the loop and it didn't. Unless I'm missing some crucial information about loops and breaks, I thought that was how it was supposed to work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @LewBloch yes, I was printing all the checks made in the loop and it was finding it. I've tried a break; and it kept printing the results, weirdly. Gonna double check on it again.

Comment: A `break;` is not a breakpoint. A breakpoint is a place where a debugging execution halts and lets you examine variable values and other useful information. It would let you know if the body of the `if` is even reached, which clearly it is not. Also, your search terms are redundant, and you're using the non-short-circuiting "OR", `|`.

Comment: Interesting. All valuable information. The lines on the if statement were being printed consistently. I don't understand why everyone seem to think that it wouldn't since the boolean flag is turned true if the user input was being checked. I was using the `|` because Java was throwing errors for the usual OR `||` on other programs I made and I totally forgot to check on it, thanks for the heads up, I've read on it now and it's a huge difference. About the array, yeah, most of those are redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a potential solution:

```
public class Class {
  private static final String[] profaneWords = {
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "llama"
  };

  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(isProfane("this is some user input."));
    System.out.println(isProfane("this is some user input containing the dirty word 'Cat'."));
    System.out.println(isProfane(" cat "));
    System.out.println(isProfane("Cat"));
  }

  private static boolean isProfane(final String input) {
    for (final String profanity : profaneWords) {
      if (input.toLowerCase().contains(profanity)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here is a streaming java8 version:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Class {
  private static final String[] profaneWords = {
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "llama"
  };

  private static boolean isProfane(final String input) {
    return Arrays.stream(profaneWords)
      .anyMatch(input.toLowerCase()::contains);
  }
}
```